# How to access field data from a related soql query field in lwc wire method

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components

I need to related field(Product_Category__r.Id) in my lwc wired method.

this is my code:

Apex controller method:

```
   @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
public static List<Product_Category__c> getCategoryByProduct(Id catalogId){
    List<Product_Category_Item__c> categories = [SELECT Product_Category__r.Id
                                                 FROM Product_Category_Item__c
                                                 WHERE Product__c IN 
                                                 (SELECT Product__c 
                                                 FROM Product_Catalog_Item__c
                                                 WHERE Catalog__c = :catalogId)];
    Set<Product_Category__c> categoryIds = new Set<Product_Category__c>();
    List<Product_Category__c> productCategories = new List<Product_Category__c>();
    for(Product_Category_Item__c category : categories){
        categoryIds.add(category.Product_Category__r);
    }

    productCategories.addAll(categoryIds);
    return productCategories;
}
```

js wired method:

```
    @wire(getCategoriesByProduct, {catalogId: '$catalogId'})
wiredCategoriesByProduct({data, error}){
    if(data && this.catalogId != undefined){
        this.categories = data;
        this.cateogryId = this.categories.Product_Category__r.Id;
        console.log(this.categories)
        console.log(this.categoryId + 'Category from controller');
    }else if(error){
        this.error = error;
        console.log(this.error);
    }
}
```

When I log (this.CategoryId) I'm getting this error: [Cannot read property 'Id' of undefined].

How can I accces that field on my lwc wired method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your returned productCategories variable is a List of Product_Category__c (not Product_Category_Item__c), and will return as a JavaScript array. You will need to loop through the returned Categories and will be able to access the Id on each item directly. For example:

```
this.categories = data;
for (var i in categories) {
    this.cateogryId = categories[i].Id;
    console.log(this.cateogryId);
}
```